# Dynamic PointAnimation in Microsoft Surface using MVVM-Light

Tags: c#, animation, dynamic, mvvm-light, pixelsense

I'm currently developing a game in C# for the Surface platform (.NET 4.0) using MVVM Light. I'm looking for a way to incorporate dynamic PointAnimations (Translation) into a MVVM project (or find out that it's not possible). I'm not a MVVM purist, but if it could be fitted into MVVM, all the better.

Visually I'm trying to automatically translate a ScatterViewItem to another location on the ScatterView. The new location is calculated after the user presses a button on the Surface.

I've used RelayCommands and know of the different uses of the Messenger and RaisePropertyChanged events, but I can't figure out where the animations go. The data to build them is in the ViewModel, but obviously the animations will play in the View. So if it is possible at all, I don't get what parts should go where, or should I somehow build them in the ViewModel, and then send the list to the View?

I've only seen XAML based animations coupled with MVVM Light (Laurent Bugnion's MIX11 presentation/sample). So perhaps I'm guilty of committing MVVM-heresy, in that case I might have to abandon MVVM.

In my non-MVVM satellite project, I'm using the following code, which works very nicely:

```
    private void btnStartAnimation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointAnimation oPointAnimation;

        oPointAnimation = new PointAnimation();
        oPointAnimation.From = new Point(GreenOne.ActualCenter.X, GreenOne.ActualCenter.Y);
        oPointAnimation.To = new Point(GreenOne.ActualCenter.X + 300, GreenOne.ActualCenter.Y);
        oPointAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

        oPointAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        oPointAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(OnAnimation_Completed);
        GreenOne.BeginAnimation(ScatterViewItem.CenterProperty, oPointAnimation,HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
    }

    //make it hold its position and make it movable again
    private void OnAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point center = GreenOne.ActualCenter;

        GreenOne.BeginAnimation(ScatterViewItem.CenterProperty, null);
        GreenOne.Center = center;


    }
```